# Unable to download csv using php script

Tags: php, csv, download, web-crawler

I have searched existing questions on this topic but I couldn't find the solution. Requesting your attention to help me solve this problem.

I am trying to create a script to get csv file from a distant source (and upload it to the DB). I am getting the following error:

> Warning:fopen(http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in /home/path/csvUploadScript.php on line 20
>   Error opening data file.

I have checked php.ini file: allow_url_fopen is set "On"

This is the code I have to get the file contents:

```
`define('CSV_PATH','http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/');
$csvfile = CSV_PATH . "sec_bhavdata_full.csv"; 
$file = fopen($csvfile,"r");`
```

The uploading part works alright when the csv file is available on the same server but it gives error when I try to upload the csv directly from the nseindia site.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Put these lines in your code

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your filename.csv"');
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Running the script with these lines, downloads the file to my PC. I want to fetch content of the csv and upload it in DB directly without downloading. I did not share the uploading part of script above but the same script is supposed to use the csv for data upload to DB as well.

Answer (score 1):

add this on top of your code before echo the output

```
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . date('Y-m-d H.i.s') . ' - file-namw.csv');
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Adding these lines, downloads the file to my PC. I want to fetch content of the csv and upload it in DB directly without downloading.

Comment: @ruchi dear you can find simple solution here http://www.codechewing.com/library/read-csv-file-data-insert-into-database-php/
and if this solution is work for you please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```html
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your filename.csv"'');
```